# How can I re-write the conditionals for this button

Tags: react.js, typescript, jsx

I've been trying out React for a couple of days and I tried to build a button component with some conditionals. Everything works but I feel like I am not doing it the right way.

Could anyone review my code and give me some advice and tell me what I am doing wrong or what i could do better. I think I am using too many return statements.

I use Typescript for type checking.

Would appreciate any help!

````
import { Link } from "gatsby";

interface Props {
  content: string,
  color: string,
  path?: string,
  type?: string
}

export default function Button(props: Props): JSX.Element {
  let elementType;

  const checkProps = () => {
    const availableColors = ['blue', 'grey', 'dark-grey', 'white'];
    const borderColors = [''];
    let buttonStyle;

    // Check if props.color exists in availableColors
    if(!availableColors.includes(props.color)) {
      console.error(`"${props.color} color key not available for button style`);
      return;
    }
    
    buttonStyle = buttonStyles[`button--${props.color}`];

    // Check if props.content is valid
    if(!props.content) {
      console.error(`"${props.content} is not valid as content`);
      return;
    }

    // Check if props.type exists
    if(!props.type) {
      elementType = <button className={ buttonStyle }>{ props.content }</button>
      return;
    }

    if(props.type !== 'link') {
      console.error(`"${props.type} is not a valid type, use 'link' instead or use nothing for default button`);
      return;
    } else {
        elementType = <Link to={ props.path } className={ buttonStyle }>{ props.content }</Link>
    }
  }

  checkProps();

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      { elementType }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}```
````

Answer (score 2):

**Narrow types with TypeScript instead of erroring** There are many places in the code where you check a condition based on how the Button is being called, and if it isn't fulfilled, you log an error and return nothing. This is a reasonable approach in JavaScript, but in TypeScript, you have a much better option, which is to use types to require *only certain* arguments. This way, rather than an error being thrown at runtime, an error will be thrown by TypeScript at compile-time when a user of `Button` attempts to pass props that aren't valid. Turning typos / accidental incorrect function calls into compile-time errors is one of the greatest advantages of TypeScript, and it's great that you're using TypeScript already, so go ahead and take advantage of it.

For example, rather than:

```
const availableColors = ['blue', 'grey', 'dark-grey', 'white'];
const borderColors = [''];
let buttonStyle;

// Check if props.color exists in availableColors
if(!availableColors.includes(props.color)) {
  console.error(`"${props.color} color key not available for button style`);
  return;
}
```

You can make `availableColors` as a *type* instead, and require that the `color` prop matches it:

`'blue' | 'grey' | 'dark-grey' | 'white'`

Similarly, rather than

```
if(!props.content) {
  console.error(`"${props.content} is not valid as content`);
```

you can require that the `content` property is of type:

```
T & (T extends '' ? 'Content must not be empty' : {})
```

and instead of

```
if(props.type !== 'link') {
```

require a `type` of `'link' | ''` exactly.

Using the above methods will also let you declare `buttonStyle` and `elementType` with `const` - or you could even inline their values into the props.

**Default export?** You have:

```
export default function Button
```

This will mean that the imported button is not really tied to its `Button` name anymore. For example, it would be easy for someone to initially type:

```
import button from './Button';
```

only to run into problems since they forgot to capitalize it. Using named exports makes these sorts of typos more difficult, because one has to *intentionally* rename it to get something other than Button:

```
// Natural import
import { Button } from './Button';
```

or

```
// Deliberate renaming
import { Button as RenamedVariableName } from './Button';
```

**Destructure immediately** Rather than referencing `props` multiple times in the function body, you might consider extracting the properties from the props immediately in the function definition - it makes the logic later less noisy.

**Let TS infer types when possible** There's no need to note that a function returns a particular type if

- TypeScript can already infer the type automatically, and
- The type is obvious to a reader of a code at a glance

So, you may consider removing the `JSX.Element` from `(props: Props): JSX.Element`.

**`buttonStyles`?** It sounds like `buttonStyles` is an object that contains strings, where the strings are class names. So `buttonStyles` isn't a very precise variable name - it doesn't contain *styles*, it contains *class names*. Maybe instead call it `buttonClassNamesByColor`?

**Fragments** In newer versions of React, you may use `<>` and `</>` instead of `<React.Fragment>` `</React.Fragment>`. Or, even better, since you're returning *only a single JSX element* regardless, you can use the conditional operator to return either one or the other element, without wrapping everything in a fragment.

```
export const Button = <T extends string>({
    content,
    color,
    path,
    type,
}: {
    content: T & (T extends '' ? 'Content must not be empty' : {});
    color: 'blue' | 'grey' | 'dark-grey' | 'white';
    path?: string;
    type: '' | 'link';
}) => {
    const buttonClassName = buttonClassNamesByColor[`button--${color}`];
    return type === ''
        ? <button className={buttonClassName}>{content}</button>
        : <Link to={path} className={buttonClassName}>{content}</Link>;
}
```